# UnboundLocalError at /signin/ local variable 'user' referenced before assignment in Django

Tags: python, django, function, authentication

### Function to let the user to login as follows=>

---

Obviously this error pops:

```
def login_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password =password  )
  if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
  elif user is None:
                      return render(request, "covi/signin.html", {
            "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
        })
  else:
                      return render(request, "covi/signin.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because
`user = authenticate(request, username=username, password =password)` runs only if `request.method == 'POST'`. If you do a GET request user won't be assigned.

```
def login_view(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password =password  )
    if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    elif user is None:
      return render(request, "covi/signin.html", {
            "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
      })
  return render(request, "covi/signin.html")
```